# Discover not working on Asashi Linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux

Im currently running Asashi linux on an Apple M1 MacBook Air. However, when I try to access discover, it shows that it can't load the apps because "the app backend is not available." How do I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is Discover? What research have you done and what have you tried? Have you looked into figuring out what the backend is the warning is telling you about?

Comment: discover seems to be the app store for Asashi linux